# Close last div after loop with unknown iteration ( logical question )

Tags: php, html

if I have loops within an unknown iteration, how would **you** ensure the last div gets closed after the last run? I am not sure if my logic is right here of if there's just a more effective way.

For example, I need 6 "sub-col" (could be in a different szenario I just need 4 or 3 "sub-col").
Loop can run completely random times.

```
<?php

$loop_iteration = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( $loop_iteration % 6 == 0 ) {
        if ( $loop_iteration != 0 ) { echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->'; }

        echo '<div class="sub-row row">';
        echo '<div class="sub-inner">';
    }

    echo '<div class="sub-col">';

    /* do stuff */

    echo '</div>';

    $loop_iteration++;

endwhile;

// here I also could make a function, but for demonstration I let it as 'if'
if (
    $loop_iteration % 6 == 1
    ||  $loop_iteration % 6 == 2
    ||  $loop_iteration % 6 == 3
    ||  $loop_iteration % 6 == 4
    ||  $loop_iteration % 6 == 5
) {
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->';
}

?>
```

Same loop, different check

```
<?php

$loop_iteration = 0;
$div_status     = 'close';

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( $loop_iteration % 6 == 0 ) {
        if ( $loop_iteration != 0 ) { echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->'; }

        echo '<div class="sub-row row">';
        echo '<div class="sub-inner">';
        $div_status = 'open';
    }

    echo '<div class="sub-col">';

        /* do stuff */

    echo '</div>';

    $loop_iteration++;

endwhile;

if ( $div_status == 'open' ) {
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->';
}

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: assign condition to a boolean variable .do close only if condition met

Answer (score 0):

Just move open and closed tags outside your loop:

```
$loop_iteration = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ($loop_iteration !== 0) {
        echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';
        echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->';
    }
    echo '<div class="sub-row row">';
    echo '<div class="sub-inner">';
    echo '<div class="sub-col">';

    /* do stuff */

    echo '</div>';

    $loop_iteration++;

endwhile;

if ($loop_iteration > 0) {
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-inner -->';
    echo '</div> <!-- sub-row -->';
}
```

Comment: In your example the last 'sub-row' would be always empty.

Comment: Well, the modulus operator got lost. Right now the code got ONE col in each row - I need e.g. 6* col in 1* row.